# Pandas: Identify Date ranges that contain date 'x' in list

Tags: python, pandas

The code maybe explains the question better, but I have a list of date ranges (month start, month end for example) in a dataframe, and then a list of birthdays.

I'm simply trying to create a dataframe column that contains the birthdate days (or a list of them) if its in between a StartDate and EndDate.

Sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
end = [x for x in pd.date_range(dt.date(2022,1,1),periods=12, freq=pd.offsets.MonthEnd(1)).values]
start = [x for x in pd.date_range(dt.date(2022,1,1),periods=12, freq=pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)).values]

dates = [(x, y) for x, y in zip(start, end)]

df = pd.DataFrame(dates, columns = ['StartDate', 'EndDate'])

birthdays = [dt.date(2022, 6, 17), dt.date(2022, 10, 7),dt.date(2022, 10, 12), dt.date(2022, 11 ,15)]
```

Expected solution (in dataframe terms! :) )

```
from numpy import nan
solution = [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, [dt.date(2022, 6, 17)], nan, nan, nan, [dt.date(2022, 10, 7),dt.date(2022, 10, 12)], [dt.date(2022, 11 ,15)], nan]
df['Solution'] = solution
```

[image: solution]

Is there a way to do that kind of lookup, without looping through each date in birthdays?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Kindly post the expected output dataframe

Comment: Are your start and end dates always the month start and month end? If that is the case you just care about what month each birthdays falls in, which is simple problem to solve.

Comment: Nope, month start/end was just a simple example to use in this case.

Comment: Let me see if I can jimmy up a solution df

Comment: added a solution - hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `merge_asof`:

```
df['Solution'] = (df['StartDate'].map(
  pd.merge_asof(pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(birthdays, name='Solution')),
               df,
               left_on='Solution', right_on='StartDate'
              )
   .groupby('StartDate')['Solution'].agg(list)
))
```

output:

```
    StartDate    EndDate                                    Solution
0  2022-01-01 2022-01-31                                         NaN
1  2022-02-01 2022-02-28                                         NaN
2  2022-03-01 2022-03-31                                         NaN
3  2022-04-01 2022-04-30                                         NaN
4  2022-05-01 2022-05-31                                         NaN
5  2022-06-01 2022-06-30                       [2022-06-17 00:00:00]
6  2022-07-01 2022-07-31                                         NaN
7  2022-08-01 2022-08-31                                         NaN
8  2022-09-01 2022-09-30                                         NaN
9  2022-10-01 2022-10-31  [2022-10-07 00:00:00, 2022-10-12 00:00:00]
10 2022-11-01 2022-11-30                       [2022-11-15 00:00:00]
11 2022-12-01 2022-12-31                                         NaN
```

Comment: Nice, thanks Mozway.  At midnight last night, I was thinking that I might also be able to use an apply(lambda x: list(filter)) with a <=, >= date function or something. This is way cleaner.

Comment: When you ran this mozway, did the datetime's in Solution populate as Timestamp objects, or datetimes?

Comment: They are `datetime64[ns]`

Comment: Huh, weird.   I just noticed that the solution has one 'error' though.  If there are birthdays in the list > max(EndDate), they all get lumped into the last row. Any thoughts on how to fix that? My fault for not including that edge case in the example.

Comment: @keynesiancross yes, as your bins were discrete I assumed there was no such case. Easy workaround, pre-filter birthdays to remove the out of bounds values ;)